# Vue3 How to init another vue instances in an existing vue instance

Tags: vuejs3, aem

I am developing a website using a system called AEM, which allows users to add and drag pre-made components onto the page, similar to Wix. I am using Vue3 for development, and each component is an HTML file with the following structure:

**component-a.html**

```
    <div class="component-a" id="${component.cellName}">
    </div>
    <sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='myproject.vue3'}"></sly>
    <sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='myproject.componentA'}"></sly>
    <script>
    (function () {
            const componentID = "${component.cellName}";
            initComponentA(componentID);
        })();
    </script>
```

Using the  directive allows the js file to be loaded on the current page for use. I load js and write IIFE in HTML to init the instance

${component.cellName} is randomly generated by AEM.

**componentA.js**

```
function initComponentA(componentID){
    const { ref,createApp } = Vue3
    const app = createApp({
    setup() {
    }
    })
    
    app.mount(`#${componentID}`)
}
```

The problem is that I currently have a child component that users can drag and drop onto component A(they can drop one or more), and after the user drags it onto component A, the webpage structure become nested and looks like the following.

```
<div class="component-a" id="${component.cellName}">
    <div class="child-component" id="${component.cellName}">
    </div>
    <sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='myproject.vue3'}"></sly>
    <sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='myproject.childComponent'}"></sly>
    <script>
    (function () {
            const componentID = "${component.cellName}";
            initChildComponent(componentID);
        })();
    </script>
</div>
<sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='myproject.vue3'}"></sly>
<sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='myproject.componentA'}"></sly>
<script>
 (function () {
   const componentID = "${component.cellName}";
   initComponentA(componentID);
  })();
</script>
```

and then the vue instance of the child component seems not worked, is there any solution? thanks in advance.

note: I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46076412/vue-instance-inside-another-vue-instance), but it's using vue2 and the solution below don't work for me.

Comment: The question is: Why do you want it? I don't think it's a good idea at all to put a Vue app inside a Vue app. This could cause conflicts.

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48894972/2487565